# bootmgr missing after restoring with sysresccd

Tags: windows-7, linux, mbr, system-restore

I backed up my laptop months ago. Today i repartition the drive and used sysresccd with partimage to restore the HDD. I got a success msg after restoring however when booting i get a bootmgr missing error. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put grub back in the MBR, and the "no-man's land" between the MBR and the first partition. Usually this is done with `grub-install`. If you are doing this from a live CD (sysresccd) then you need to tell it the location of your hard drive partition, like this:

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda1
```

where `/mnt` is where the partition is mounted and `/dev/sda1` is the Linux name of the partition.

However, this installs whatever version of grub is on the live CD, rather than the one that's in the restored partition. You can use this to get your system booted and then run grub-install again from the booted system.

Alternatively, since your `/boot/grub` directory already contains the right files, you can use the lower-level `grub-setup` command:

```
grub-setup --directory=/mnt/boot/grub (hd0,0)
```

Then you don't need to re-run `grub-install` after booting.

**Remember:** modify `/dev/sda` and `(hd0,0)` above as appropriate for your system.

Answer (score 0):

Neil's instructions will get you GRUB back on the MBR. If it's the Windows bootloader that you want, you'll need these steps.

This site has complete instructions on the repair of the Windows Vista/7 bootloader. http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/how-to-repair-the-windows-vista-bootloader/

Comment: It would be polite to mention that you are affiliated with neosmart.

Comment: My apologies. I shall do that in the future. :)

Comment: It might be sensible to update your existing answers too.