# Windows XP Cant install STOP error 0x0000007B

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-xp, mbr

When i insert my XP cd before i could get to the install or repair screen i get this error

[image]

I [found this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;314082) and i am unsure what the problem is. Does it not like my HD? XP installed on my laptop in the past but i just got it back today from warranty service and they changed the HD. It should be the same type. NOTE: I did mess up the MBR badly. Bad enough to not be able to install Win7 which has been solved since. [I broke my MBR/Windows doesnt let me reformat!](https://superuser.com/questions/158743/i-broke-my-mbr-windows-doesnt-let-me-reformat)

Answer (score 3):

Ahh they were messing with my bios. The bios allows the HD to be used in 2 different ways. It was set to AHCI and i changed it to ATA which then solved the problem. I changed this before i ever installed XP in the past thus i never seen the error screen before or realize the problem.

Comment: That's exactly it. :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it figured out. That is defiantly not something I would have thought of.

Comment: Yay! Way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my other comment:

The microsoft article is only relevant if you moved an already installed XP disk over to a different computer. You are installing xp from scratch so the article does not apply. The error message indicates that there might be file system corruption. You can try right clicking on the c drive in explorer click properties > tools and under "error-checking" click "check now". It should do a self check on reboot.

Lets see where that gets us.

**Edit**:

This error could easily be related to your dual boot installation process. You might like this step by step [guide](http://lifehacker.com/5126781/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-with-xp-or-vista). Note that the guide assumes you have xp installed first.

Comment: i found the problem. see my answer.